# get rid of dropdown list on views exposed filter

Tags: 7, views, navigation

I created a view with an exposed filter, that I set to autosubmitt. So when I start typing in the filter field, the list of items does get filtered live. So far I'm happy.

What I don't like is the dropdown list that also gets updated while typing. How can I tell this field to stop showing a dropdown list at all?

Answer (score 1):

the 2 general options in the view are autocomplete and dropdown.  the autocomplete will give you a list of matching queries as you type.  keep in mind that if you remove that and somebody spells something incorrectly they will not get any results from the exposed filter.

if you have to get rid of the dropdown feature, use CSS to hide it.